# Flutter - Load an asset file into an external Flutter plugin

Tags: flutter, flutter-platform-channel

I am developing a Flutter plugin with native Platform View. My PlatformView needs a file which is project dependant. I want to pass my file path which is in example project to my library project (Native Android/iOS code). In simple words how can I access my project assets in external library from example/test project.

I was thinking about changing src directory in android gradle but I'm confused how to set scrc directorry to an example project.

```
flutter_library_project
    - android
        access file here
    - iOS
        access file here
    - libs

Flutter_library_sample
    - assets
        file
    - android
    - iOS
    - libs
       can access file here
```